# Xcode Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint

Tags: xcode, uitableview

Good day to all!
I write a chat like a tinder
I have a custom cell with a message view that has restrictions
5 on the bottom and 5 on the top and other restrictions on the right and left
There is also a height restriction for messages - less than or equal to 45

The trick is that when several messages come from the same user, I want the messages to be closer to each other and therefore reduce the bottom constant to 0

And if messages come from one or another user, the constant must be the same, i.e. 5

Everything works, but a warning pops up from X Code

```
Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
Try this: 
    (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
    (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it.
```

(
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x2820cb1b0 V:|-(5)-[UIView:0x1033b1630]   (active, names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x1033b0a70 )>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x2820cb200 V:[UIView:0x1033b1630]-(5)-|   (active, names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x1033b0a70 )>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x2820ca850 UIView:0x1033b1630.height >= 45   (active)>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x2820cbf20 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' UITableViewCellContentView:0x1033b0a70.height == 50   (active)>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x2820ca850 UIView:0x1033b1630.height >= 45   (active)>

I know that he means that the message-view constant is violated, but I don’t know why it will be violated
w my code

```
    if  indexPath.row + 1 < structMessagesArr[indexPath.section - 1].messages.count && structMessagesArr[indexPath.section - 1].messages[indexPath.row + 1].sender == sender {
        cell.avatar.image = UIImage()
        cell.bottomMessageViewConstrains.constant = 0
    }else {
        cell.bottomMessageViewConstrains.constant = 5
    }
```

It says here if the user is the same, then we decrease the constant, if not, we set it to 5

Please tell me where my message-view constant is being violated

I tried to dig into the prepare method before using the cell and set the value to default i.e. 5
But got the same error

```
override func prepareForReuse() { 
    
    heartLikeView.isHidden = false
    rightMessageViewConstrainsToSuperView.isActive = false
    
    currentUser = false
    
    rightMessageViewConstrainsToHeartView.constant = 5
    rightMessageViewConstrainsToSuperView.constant = 5
    leftMessageViewConstrainsToSuperView.constant = 5
   
    statusMessage.image = UIImage(named: "SendMessageTimer")

    labelRightConstrainsToMessageView.constant = 22
    rightMessageViewConstrainsToHeartView.isActive = true
}
```